# Picker set to navigationLink doesn't show any labels

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a Picker that is set to navigationLink. When you click the picker you are correctly taken through to the picker page. It then renders the list of options and a tick for the selected options. But all the options are blank text. When you click on one it changes correctly and the label on the main page updates correctly. I am only seeing this issue on iPad and not iPhone.

I have a similar picker below but set the style to 'menu' and that shoes labels just fine, but its not what i want for this UI (the labels are long).

[image]

Has anyone seen this issue before and know how to fix it?

I have the following code which renders a picker, specifically in the `.navigationLink` style. Its rendered in a popover with a navigation stack.

```
Picker(
    String(
        localized: "Single Tap",
        comment: "The label that is shown next to the single tap action"
    ),
    selection: $tapAction
) {
    ForEach(Action.tapCases) { currentTapAction in
        Text(currentTapAction.display)
    }
}.pickerStyle(.navigationLink)
```

Here is the code for the `Action` enum that is being used.

```
enum Action: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable, Codable {
    case next, back, none, fast, select, delete, clear, startScanning
    var id: Self { self }
    
    static public var tapCases: [Action] = [.next, .back, .none, .select, .delete, .clear, .startScanning]
    static public var holdCases: [Action] = [.next, .back, .none, .fast, .select, .delete, .clear, .startScanning]

    var display: String {
        switch self {
        case .none: return String(
            localized: "None",
            comment: "Label for action that happens on a keypress"
        )
        case .next: return String(
            localized: "Go to the next item",
            comment: "Label for action that happens on a keypress"
        )
        case .back: return String(
            localized: "Go to the previous item",
            comment: "Label for action that happens on a keypress"
        )
        case .fast: return String(
            localized: "Quickly scan through the items",
            comment: "Label for action that happens on a keypress"
        )
        case .select: return String(
            localized: "Select the currently selected item",
            comment: "Label for action that happens on a keypress"
        )
        case .delete: return String(
            localized: "Delete the last inputted letter",
            comment: "Label for action that happens on a keypress"
        )
        case .clear: return String(
            localized: "Clear all the inputted text",
            comment: "Label for action that happens on a keypress"
        )
        case .startScanning: return String(
            localized: "Start scanning from the current item, scanning must be enabled",
            comment: "Label for action that happens on a keypress"
        )
        }
    }
}
```